# Check value if present do nothing if not present add them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables History and feed. both have 103 columns 1'st column is a unique key
, the second last column is checksum and the last column is Flag which tells if the row is new or updated. checksum column has a value of all the 100 columns in between the unique key and checksum.
Example:

```
| UniqueKey | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | CheckSum | Flag |
| --------- | ---- | ---- | ---- | -------- | ---- |
| Uk1       | A    | B    | C    | 123      | N    |
| Uk2       | D    | E    | F    | 456      | U    |
| Uk3       | G    | H    | I    | 789      | N    |
| Uk4       | J    | K    | L    | 101112   | N    |
```

I have 3 scenarios:

Scenario-1: if uniquekey and checksum both are present in the feed table do nothing.

Scenario-2: if UniqueKey is present but the corresponding checksum is different add the row in the feed table and add the value of the flag as U.

Scenario-3: If the combination of uniquekey and checksum is not present add the row and value of flag as N.

I tried using the while loop, in the below code i just tried to iterate through the table so that loop only runs till the count of records present in the table. but after that I am unable to use if statements to achieve the scenarios.

```
Declare @count int
select @count =  count(*) from [HumanResources].[Department]

declare @i int=0
while @i<=@count
begin
    declare @Name varchar(100)
    --select @Name=name from [HumanResources].[Department] where DepartmentID=@i
    if (select @Name=name from [HumanResources].[Department] where DepartmentID=@i)
    begin

    end
    set @i=@i+1
end
```

Comment: So what do you need help with? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: How is the history table relevant? And seems that conditions 2 & 3 are the same, i.e. add a new row, so can just check the checksum and ignore the id?

Comment: You won't need a cursor for sure, just an `insert where not exists()`.

Comment: @DaleK
the reason I am using the history table is that it will hold7 days of data, so if the Unique key and checksum are present in the feed table do not add the row.

if the unique key and checksum are not present then add the row and flag as N
if the unique key exists and the checksum is absent then add the row and add flag as U